# Вывод записей mysql (не выводить меньший id)

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите пожалуйста. Есть таблица, в ней 5 записей с неизвестными id.

```
id
10
20
30
40
50
```

Как я могу сделать выборку что бы вывести таблицу в таком порядке (не выводить меньший id из всех)

```
id
20
30
40
50
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select id
  from table
 order by id
  limit 1, 100000
```

Первое значение в limit - сколько записей пропускать. Второе - сколько показывать, его лучше задать побольше, если требуется заведомо получить все записи таблицы.

Пример на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1056239/1)

Comment: Проблема в том что я не знаю какие id есть

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин Это не имеет значения. В лимите указано количество записей, а не их абсолютные значения

Comment: Понял, спасибо, работает.